# How to create a database link to a local access db from oracle remote db

Tags: oracle, ms-access, database-link

I have a requirement from my client to access a locally installed access database through a oracle remote database. These separate access databases are in their user's laptops. Is it possible to create a one database link in the remote oracle database to work in every laptop? How we can create this link?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205)

Comment: You cannot have oracle start reaching out and linking to someone's laptop or say their banking data on their laptop. You most certainly can have the client application(s) link to the oracle system. So it is the client application that you can and will link to oracle. The simple approach is to use the external data tab in the ribbon and link to the oracle database.

Comment: This requirement is simplified. They have only one laptop it has the access database. And oracle database in the server. I need to read and write data to access database from oracle end. Hope I can use oracle ODBC driver and create a db link.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a step-by-step guide,

actions in database1
++++++++++++++++++++

```
create user dbuser1 identified by pass1
create public databaselink "dblinkname1" connect to dbuser2 using "entry in tnsnames.ora/connect string   to database2"
select * from dual@dblinkname1   <-   should returns X
```

actions in database2
++++++++++++++++++++

```
create user dbuser2 identified by pass2
create public databaselink "dblinkname2" connect to dbuser1 using "entry in tnsnames.ora/connect string  to database1"
select * from dual@dblinkname2    <-   should returns X
```

maybe you want to create synonyms for objects and give some grants.